# how to easily check if a std::map and std::unordered_map contains the same elements

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing a Google Test unit test, and I want to check if the content of an `unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` is the same as an `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

I don't think `std::equal` will work, as elements in the `std::map` are sorted according a criterion. The order is not important.

Comment: You can iterate over one or the other and verify that the values for each key are the same.

Comment: Are you using gmock? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/kz4tACpCBME UnorderedElementsAreArray would work nicely here.

Comment: @FDinoff Nope only Google Test ! I never used Gmock yet, but your comment is interesting ! is it easy to include Gmock to GTest ?

Comment: @Aminos AFAIK gtest includes gmock. So it shouldn't be that hard to include. gmock was built to be used with gtest.

Comment: Can you please tell me breafly what Gmock can bring to a GTest ? Does it facilitate the creation of Fakes / Test doubles ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is nicer way than just going over all elements of one map and checking if they are present in the other map. If you also check that the amount of elements is the same, you'll know whether the maps are completely the same.

For example:

```
template<typename K, typename E>
bool maps_equal(const std::map<K, E> &map, const std::unordered_map<K, E> &unordered_map) {
    return
        map.size() == unordered_map.size() &&
        std::all_of(map.cbegin(), map.cend(), [&](const std::pair<const K, E> &item) {
            auto iter = unordered_map.find(item.first);
            return iter != unordered_map.end() && iter->second == item.second;
        });
}
```

Comment: I added a third parameter to the template definition (above and to std::map<K, F, C> ;) ) my std::map uses a custom comaparator to be able to compile it. It works ! tests are passed too. Thank you !

Comment: Hi, I just made small improvement to prevent unnecessary copies of the keys and values. (The "std::all_of" line changed.)

Comment: @Aminos: in that case beware that if the map and the unordered map are using different definitions of "equal keys", then checking that the sizes match and one is a subset of the other is not necessarily sufficient to test that they're the same. For example suppose the map contains keys `X` and `Y`, the unordered_map contains keys `Y` and `Z`, but also considers `X` and `Y` to be equal and therefore reports both `X` and `Y` to be present.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an `unordered_map` with a `map`, and then compare two `unordered_map`. And vice versa.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m1;
std::map<std::string, std::string> m2;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m3(m2.begin(), m2.end());
if (m1 == m3) {}
```

Comment: This is likely to have a much better time complexity than trying to find each element in the map manually. Nice answer.

Comment: Actually both this and the accepted answer have the same time complexity: O(n). However this answer makes several allocations and copies of the stored elements. The accepted answer does not, it works purely on immutable data.

Answer (score 1):

I will ask an obvious question, but it really changes *everything*:

> Is the notion of equality in the `map` compatible with the notion of equality in the `unordered_map`?

As an example of incompatible definitions:

```
struct Point3D { std::int32_t x, y, z };

struct MapLess {
    bool operator()(Point3D const& left, Point3D const& right) const {
       return std::tie(left.x, left.y) < std::tie(right.x, right.y);
    }
};

bool operator==(Point3D const& left, Point3D const& right) {
    return std::tie( left.x,  left.z)
        == std::tie(right.x, right.z);
}
```

In this (contrived) case, we could have:

- `map`: `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 3, 3)`
- `unordered_map`: `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 2, 4)`

and a naive look-up would report that the `map` is included in the `unordered_map` which since they both have the same size would lead to the erroneous conclusion that they are equal.

---

The solution if a canonical notion of equality exists is to verify, after each look-up, that the look-up result is effectively the same as the original.

```
template <typename M1, typename M2>
bool equal(M1 const& left, M2 const& right) {
    if (left.size() != right.size()) { return false; }

    for (auto const& e: left) {
        auto const it = right.find(e.first);

        if (it == right.end()) { return false; }
        if (it->first != e.first) { return false; }
        if (it->second != e.second) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```

*Note: this could be rewritten with `std::all` and a single boolean expression; it's a matter of taste, I prefer breaking it down.*

If no canonical notion of equality exists, then a reverse look-up can replace the equality check:

```
template <typename M1, typename M2>
bool equal(M1 const& left, M2 const& right) {
    if (left.size() != right.size()) { return false; }

    for (auto e = left.begin(), end = left.end(); e != end; ++e) {
        auto const it = right.find(e->first);

        if (it != right.end()) { return false; }
        if (left.find(it->first) != e) { return false; }
        if (it->second != e->second) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is of course slightly more expensive.